# Best way to group java objects by multiple fields

Tags: java

Have an object something like this

```
public class Person {

private String id;    
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Float weight;
private Date birthday;
private String address;
.....
```

**Need to group list of persons by 5 fields(firstName, lastName, weight, birthday, address) having as a result map**

```
Map<String, List<Person>> groupedPersons = ...
```

There is a solution doing this by guava Equivalence:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html

**Are there other (better) ways?**

Comment: What is the point of having entries grouped by different key? I can see only one solution - group by each field and then take the union of all maps.

Answer (score 0):

I Will use hashCode() method:

```
 @Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (weight != null ? weight.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (birthday != null ? birthday.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

then use the map: HashMap> groupPersons ...

Comment: `Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName, weight, birthday, address)` would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods that a class needs to override to make objects of that class work as hash map keys:

```
public int hashCode();
public boolean equals(Object o);
```

You can then use a HashMap to distinct the group values.
If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value will be replaced by`HashMap.put(K key, V value)`.

Eclipse can auto-generate and override API automatically.